# How to create separate file for each class in a java file in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, automated-refactoring

I have a java file with multiple classes like below .

```
public class ABC {


    public static void main(String[] args){}
}

class A{}

class B{}

class C{}
```

And I have 50 + classes like these . Is there a way to create a separate file for each of these classes in netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure if there is a quick way of doing it as I haven't used netbeans in a long time but you can right-click on your package and create a new class for each internal class you have.